# Mod latest news to include all subcategories item

Tags: module, joomla-3.4, template-override

In the latest news module we can choose what category to be included, but we need to select all (sub) categories even when the parent category is selected.

Any idea how to display all items inside the parent category and its subcategories? I'd like to have this option so I don't have to check the module settings everytime a new sub category added.

Template override or core modification are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Articles Category module instead, as it provides a ton of options including child category article display:

[image: Articles Category category display settings]

Comment: Wow I didn't know that this exist. I'm just wondering, what is the difference between them?

Comment: The difference is that Articles Categories gives you more options on what to display and how. Feel free to mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question ;)

Comment: sorry to bother you again, i'm just curious, why the latest news module still included with the joomla package if it technically brings the same function as mod article category?

Comment: It doesn't, it's functionality is far more limited in scope; all it does is show latest items from a single category. The project as a whole is disinclined to remove old functionality, generally for backwards compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Goto backend -> Extension -> Module manager -> New -> Articles category -> Filtering options -> See the category field here you can add more than one sub categories.